# How to make vim javacomplete to work?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin

I confess that I am a beginner in using vim and this question might be as dumb as it sounds. These are what I've done so far :

1. I downloaded the latest zip file format of the script from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1785).
2. I unzipped it to the `.vim` directory that placed the files `javacomplete.vim`, `java_parser.vim` and `Reflection.java` inside the `~/.vim/autoload` directory by default.
3. The following option is set (much better, I've added it to my `.vimrc` file):

   ```
   :setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
   ```
4. `java` and `javac` are set properly in the system path variable (they work from the command line).
5. Assuming that that's all I need to do, pressing `<C-x><C-o>` (in the insert mode) doesn't do any auto-completion inside a `.java` file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `:setlocal` won't work from `.vimrc`, did you use an autocommand or just put it as in your post? The correct way is to use `autocmd Filetype java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete`.

Comment: @xaizek did as u mentioned, but still it doesn't work!

Comment: So `:set omnifunc?` shows `javacomplete#Complete` in a java-file, right? Also do you see `Reflection.class` in your home directory after trying to perform a completion?

Comment: For perfect Java autocompletion, I use Vim+eclim+Eclipse. check http://eclim.org - highly recommended. In fact, eclim brings the power of IDE in my favorite editor Vim. Some people would say there is too much overhead just for autocompletion, but personally I can't imagine efficient development in Java amoung TONS of API stuff without good autocompletion. Check this question also (it's about Android, but it's still relevant for you too) : http://goo.gl/TO71pa

Comment: Yep and yes, I can see the class file.
@DmitryFrank Sure, I will check that. Actually, I am trying to set up my vim for android development ;)

Comment: I second Dmitry on Eclim. You need to keep a daemon running to make it work, but for a big, bloated language as Java, it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Vim 7.2, there's a few issues related to how the plugin locates the java-based Reflection helper.

If you have .class listed in your wildignore or suffixes, then it can't actually locate the class file to execute.

I have a clone that I modified to get around that on github : https://github.com/cilquirm/javacomplete

Give that a go and see if it works for you